# Position of the adverb "of course"

Tags: word-order, adverbs

> ...which is of course zero.
>
> ...which of course is zero.

Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's much difference between the two. It depends on which word you wish to stress more: *which* or *zero*. (Incidentally, I would set it off with commas, but that is a matter of taste.)

This saves all the emphasis for the final word *zero*:

> ... which is, of course, *zero*.

This puts the emphasis on *which*:

> ... *which*, of course, is zero.

There is no difference in meaning, only in dramatic effect. The effect is greater if the sentence is spoken; if it is written, the effect is vanishingly small.

Comment: What is the effect of saying/writing: "... which is zero, of course."

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: I think that naturally puts the emphasis on *zero* as the final word of the meat of the sentence.

Comment: I agree with @Robusto, accept that setting *of course* off with commas is (in this case) not a matter of taste. See for example *The Elements of Style* by Strunk and White.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would prefer

> ... which is of course zero

if I wanted to stress *is* or *zero*.

> ... which of course is zero

to me sound more like

> there is no doubt, of course it is zero

putting more stress on of course.

This might be quite subjective.