# "have basically been doing something" or "have been basically doing something"

Tags: word-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Position of the adverb “of course”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5721/position-of-the-adverb-of-course)
>   [Should an adverb go before or after a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb)

I was wondering what position of an adverb relative to more than one auxiliary verbs are generally? For example, "have basically been doing something" or "have been basically doing something"? Thanks!

Comment: In the specific case of this modern use of the word "basically", I wouldn't worry too much where you put it. Basically the word itself means very little, so it can largely be ignored purely on that count. But secondly, it tends to mark you out as a bit of a "downmarket speaker", so whoever you're speaking to won't be expecting a careful choice of word order anyway.

Comment: I think it's no different to another similar adverbial usage - [of course](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5721/position-of-the-adverb-of-course), so I'm voting to close as a dup of that one (which I haven't read, basically because I don't think it's worth it).

Comment: Thanks! How about replacing basically with another more meaningful adverb such as mostly?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The case there is different from mine here. I have two auxiliary verbs "have" and "been" besides the main verb "doing". If there is only one auxiliary verb, then I know the adverb is generally placed between it and the main verb. But for the case of more than one auxiliary verbs, I need some opinion.

Comment: Okay, I've been and looked at the other one. Basically you can put these kind of adverbs more or less anywhere. Or to rephrase, you can basically put them where you like. Even, if you wish, put them basically anywhere. In short, there is *no meaningful difference*, and it's not about "correct grammar".

Comment: If there is no grammar issue, which is more frequent then?

Comment: If you swap to a more precise adverb, such as *doggedly*, you'll probably realise yourself that you wouldn't say *"I've doggedly been trying"* - you'd say *"I've been doggedly trying"*. Because "basically" is often used as an almost meaningless "filler" word, no-one will notice exactly where you put it, but you've got little chance of making it modify much more than the entire statement.

Comment: Thanks! So is the general rule to put the adverb between the last auxiliary verb and the main verb?

Comment: As I keep saying, basically it's a bit like saying "erm" - which you can basically drop in almost anywhere. At the start or end of a clause, or before/after a verb, are always firm favourites, basically.

Comment: ...for the general case, see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/). To summarise, put adverbs before/after the main verb, but there are lots of oddball idiomatic factors in play. With words like *basically, really, actually*, both the meaning and the positioning get really vague, but actually it doesn't matter much because basically they don't really mean enough for it to matter exactly what they modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pick a more concrete example,

1. I basically have been practicing violin.
2. I have been basically practicing violin.

The first says that other things have happened, I may have other occupations, but I'm mostly practicing violin.

The second says that what I'm doing is, essentially, not playing randomly or performing, but practicing violin.

These are generalizations; either sentence *can* carry the other sense depending on context, but that is how I'd compare the two.

EDIT: Changed the 1st example a bit to move the adverb out away from the main verb to show that it tends more to modify the auxiliary ("have been", which could be replaced by "am in the habit of" or "tend to") when not next to the main verb. That, I realize, is what I was driving at. And this would only hold true if the adverb can potentially modify either the auxiliary or the main verb, with different results.

Comment: I think that even if you personally thought you were making different statements with those two examples, almost no-one would make your second interpretation unless you stressed the word *practicing* - in which case it would make no difference where you'd put the word *basically* anyway.

Comment: As I said, either can carry the other sense depending on context, and I guess I should have said on stress, too. Sheesh.

Comment: The word has basically become so devoid of meaning it can slot in almost anywhere. You just throw it somewhere in the sentence, basically.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Essentially.

Comment: Ah, but whereas I could say *"we are essentially as one"*, I couldn't possibly accept *"We essentially are as one"*, because *"essentially"* still has some vestige of meaning. I reckon I could do that with *"really"* though, and maybe even *"basically"* as well.

Comment: So how do you feel about "literally"? My daughter was trained on the ahem literal meaning of the word and when not to use it, but not all of her friends have been enlightened.

Comment: Your examples do well to demonstrate the conceptual distinctions a misplaced adverb can represent, and a fine job of breaking down their alternate meanings. In support I would emphasize that in the first example the word _basically_ is stressed, while in the second example it is the word _practicing_ which is stressed.

Comment: @JeffSahol: I think your daughter is headed for a life of frustration and linguistic isolation! So far as I can tell, *"literally"* has already colonised the semantic territory of *"to a considerable extent"*, and is now making inroads into *"somewhat/quite/rather/a bit"*.